# Does libxml2 (C API) provide a way to remove a registered set of xmlOutputCallbacks, without removing ALL registered output callbacks?

Tags: c, libxml2

I am working on a custom I/O layer for libxml2 and have come across an oddity in the de-registration of Output callbacks.  There appears to be no way to remove just one set of output callbacks. Am I missing something? I can provide a working example if the following pseudo-code does not clarify the question.

```
static int _in_matcher(const char* URI)  {...}
static void* _in_opener(const char* URI) {...}
static int _in_reader(void *ctxt, char *in_buf, int buf_len) {...}
static int _in_closer(void *ctxt) {...}

int test_input_callbacks(const char *file_name)
{
    int handler = xmlRegisterInputCallbacks(
      _in_matcher,
      _in_opener,
      _in_reader,
      _in_closer,
    );

    ...
    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseFile(file_name);
    xmlFree(doc);
    ...
    xmlPopInputCallbacks();
}


static int   _out_matcher( const char *URI) {...}
static void* _out_opener( const char *URI) {...}
static int   _out_writer( void *ctxt, const char *out_buf, int buf_len) {...}
static int   _outcloser( void *ctxt) {...}

int test_output_callbacks(const char *file_name)
{
    int handler = xmlRegisterOutputCallbacks(
      _out_matcher,
      _out_opener,
      _out_writer,
      _out_closer,
    );

    ...
    int result = xmlSaveFormatFileEnc(URI, doc, NULL, 0);
    xmlFree(doc);
    ...

    /* There does not appear to be a function that 
    * removes _only_ the last output callbacks
    * registered!
    */
    ==> ?? xmlPopOutputCallbacks() ?? <==
}
```

As a work around, I added this function to my [local] version of libxml2 (2-2.9.10):

```
int
xmlPopOutputCallbacks(void)
{                                                                                                                                                                                 
    if (!xmlOutputCallbackInitialized)
        return(-1);

    if (xmlOutputCallbackNr <= 0)
        return(-1);

    xmlOutputCallbackNr--;
    xmlOutputCallbackTable[xmlOutputCallbackNr].matchcallback = NULL;
    xmlOutputCallbackTable[xmlOutputCallbackNr].opencallback = NULL;
    xmlOutputCallbackTable[xmlOutputCallbackNr].writecallback = NULL;
    xmlOutputCallbackTable[xmlOutputCallbackNr].closecallback = NULL;

    return(xmlOutputCallbackNr);
}
```

It works, but I get the nagging feeling there is either something I am missing; or there is a valid reason why libxml2 does not provide the ability to remove individual sets of output callbacks.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: It's probably unanswerable by anyone other than someone involved in the design of the API. I have no insight into the design of the API, but it's probably a complexity thing. Pop works *for you*, but a general case would require insertion and removal logic which complicates the API for limited benefit (if you're the only consumer, surely you know all the callbacks you want to register/reregister).

Comment: What gets me is that there are tests in codebase for registering and popping sets of Input callbacks (libxm2-2.9.10/runtest.c:2950); and examples for installing and using a custom I/O layer (in: http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/io1.c, out: http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/io2.c); and  (IMHO) a very simple approach to handling the insertion/removal logic -- for in/out.  Which leaves me wondering if it is a security-concern, as to why they didn't provide ability to remove just one output set.
I also posted the question to libxml2's bug-tracker.

Thanks for responding!